# What is exact difference between gravitational force and magnetic force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, magnetic-fields, orbital-motion

I've read that gravitational force  is due to mass only and magnetic field is due to moving charged particles.

But **my question is:**

1. what are other difference between them?
2. Can we set up a small system like Earth and Sun (Earth rotates around sun continuously without colliding  with the Sun) with two (bigger and smaller) magnets?
3. If no, then why Earth doesn't fall into the Sun and Magnet does?

Comment: What is the similarity between these $2$ forces?? Other than the fact that both are forces.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question, "If no, then why earth doesn't fall into the Sun and Magnet does" This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Gravitation, unlike electromagnetism, is not a force. In Newtonian physics gravitation is an acceleration and in general relativity it is a distortion of spacetime. Unlike electromagnetism gravity doesn't require the existence of charges inside the objects that are subject to it. Electric fields can only attract (or repel) objects that carry an electric charge (or dipole moment) and magnetic fields can only exert forces on objects with electric currents or magnetic dipoles in them. That's why there can be non-magnetic objects. Gravity doesn't require any such charges, so one can't prevent it.

Comment: source of the above comment is CuriousOne

Comment: @DeNiSkA There are those that think there are no true forces (including magnetism) and of them distort spacetime in some way.  Starting with Kaluza-Klein and moving on to M-theory.

Comment: Gravitation is not even a force.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're thinking about stable orbiting systems the big difference between gravity and the magnetic force is that [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) do not exist. The simplest source of a magnetic field is the [magnetic dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole). By contrast gravitational monopoles exist but gravitational dipoles do not.

The Sun and the Earth are both (approximately) gravitational monopoles, and the force between two monopoles always lies along the line joining the monopoles (this is called a [central force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force)) and it is inversely proportional to distance squared. For a central inverse square force stable orbits exist.

However magnets are (approximately) magnetic dipoles, and the [force between two magnetic dipoles is not central](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles), it depends on the relative orientation of the dipoles as well as their distance, and it is not an inverse square force. All this means that for two magnetic dipoles no stable orbits exist.

That's why you cannot make a model of the Solar System using magnets.